# How can I exclude seconds from the datetime_select helper?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I suppress the generation of the seconds tag when using the `datetime_select` helper?

I tried using the option `:include_seconds => false` (used in the `time_select` helper) but It doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override what's shown with :order, such as:

```
<%= f.datetime_select :fieldname, :order => [:month, :day, :year, :hour, :minute] %>
```

Possible options for :order are [:month, :day, :year, :hour, :minute, :second]

Comment: The order option only works for `month`, `day` and `year`, but thanks to that, I figured out that you can also declare `:discard_xxx => true`, in this specific case `:discard_seconds => true` which works pretty well. Thanks.

Comment: Ah, glad you got it sorted out. I've used hour & minutes in the ":order" but I guess it didn't make any difference.

Comment: The "discard" options don't seem to do anything either using Rails 4 - unless there is some 'magic' syntax I haven't found it by trail and error, yet.  The api-doc docs have no examples of doing this - so we are just supposed to guess.  The "seconds" are not included by default, so no need to 'discard' them.